# Read a JSON File from Resources with JsonObject

Tags: android, json

I want to assign the JSONfile inside the Resources to a instance from JsonObject and parse it.
Please guide how?

MainActivicy:

```
    boolean bool = true;
    boolean bool2=true;
    String s = "";
    input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.infojson);

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    reader.beginObject();

    while (bool==true){


        String sv ="";
        sv=reader.nextName();
        s +=sv;

        if(sv.equals("id")| sv.equals("num")){
            s +=" : " ;
            s+=(String.valueOf(reader.nextInt()));
        }
        if (sv.equals("name")){
            s +=" : " ;
            s+=reader.nextString();
        }
        s+="\t";
        bool = reader.hasNext();
    }
```

JSON Content:

```
{
    "id":"1","name":"E1","num":1111,
    "My":{"id":"2","name":"E2","num":2222}
}
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Let me update on that

Comment: I was able to read the file this way but it caused a bit of trouble.:

InputStream  input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.infojson);

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

I want to read the file through class JsonObject.

Comment: please update your question with your code

Comment: Also add your json sample

Comment: I put the code.

Comment: Probably your `json` not correct, please correct it

Comment: Maybe but how do I work with JsonObject Class?

And How do I know when I reach the end of the first object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model to parse your `json` like below:

```
class ResourseResponse {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String num;

    //getter-setter
}
```

Then parse your `json` from `JsonReader` and create your model.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
Gson gson = new Gson();

if (reader.peek() != JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        ResourseResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, ResourseResponse.class);

        //Add to list
    }
    reader.endArray();
} else {
    ResourseResponse message = gson.fromJson(reader, ResourseResponse.class);

}
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot...
but How do I read two objects in a file?
  How do I know if the parser has reached the next object?

Comment: `reader.hasNext()` indicates if there is more object. Please try to debug and check inside `while` loop

Comment: I used this method(reader.hasNext()) but this is only for the current object.
So I used this:(END_DOCUMENT)
     
        while ( reader.peek() != JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT){
...
}

Json Content:

{
"1":{"id":"1","name":"E1","num":"1111"},
  "2":{"id":"2","name":"E2","num":"2222"}
}

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved.
Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: What is the Gson?

Comment: **Gson** is a popular library to handle `json` response. `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'`

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON content is not too big, you can easily create org.json.JSONObject and iterate its keys.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"E1\",\"num\":1111, \"My\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"E2\",\"num\":2222} }"
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
json.keys().forEachRemaining(x -> {
    System.out.println(x.toString());
    try {
        if (json.get(x.toString()) instanceof JSONObject) {
            System.out.println(json.get(x.toString())); / here you can iterate the internal json object
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Output is: 
num

name

id

My

{"num":2222,"name":"E2","id":"2"}